i keep geting this error gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
i got an existing project with react-native and i tried to run the project after i installed all the dependencies, fixed the environment variables and changed to the right node version but i keep getting this error and it would build the app in my emulator. I cant seem to find the solution to this has anyone seen this?
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
141 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 139 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find stetho-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find fresco-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find drawee-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:drawee:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/drawee/2.2.0/drawee-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find nativeimagefilters-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagefilters:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/nativeimagefilters/2.2.0/nativeimagefilters-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find memory-type-native-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-native:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/memory-type-native/2.2.0/memory-type-native-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find memory-type-java-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/memory-type-java/2.2.0/memory-type-java-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find imagepipeline-native-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-native:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-native/2.2.0/imagepipeline-native-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find imagepipeline-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline/2.2.0/imagepipeline-2.2.0.aar
   > Could not find android-image-cropper-2.7.0.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/2.7.0/android-image-cropper-2.7.0.aar
   > Could not find blurview-1.6.3.aar (com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.aar
   > Could not find fbcore-2.2.0.aar (com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fbcore/2.2.0/fbcore-2.2.0.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01


Maybe the project has been updated and have a forgot configuration from some dependence to change. I figured out an issue on React Native repo with this, check it. Could not find com.facebook.fresco.stetho #32944. Verify the Flipper version on android/gradle.properties.
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0

Credit to: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32944#issuecomment-1020002886
